# How to install CA certificate on Nexus 3?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, nexus3

I have installed Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.0.2-02 on my CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708.

Also I have CA certificate:

```
Issued to: \*.mycompany.com  
Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2  
Valid from 2016-11-12 to 2018-01-11
```

The RSA private key match with my CA certificate, which was checked with [Certificate Key Matcher](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html) and reported:

> The certificate and private key match!

In Nexus3 directory I made the following changes:

Added to the file `org.sonatype.nexus.cfg` the lines:

```
nexus-args=${karaf.etc}/jetty.xml,${karaf.etc}/jetty-http.xml,${karaf.etc}/jetty-requestlog.xml,${karaf.etc}/jetty-https.xml     
application-port-ssl=8443
```

Added to `jetty-https.xml` file next lines:

```
KeyStorePath /ssl/test.jks  
KeyStorePassword 123456  
KeyManagerPassword 123456  
TrustStorePath ssl/test.jks  
TrustStorePassword 123456
```

Created SSL directory in `$NEXUS_HOME/etc/` and created inside the SSL directory a Java keystore file `test.jks` with command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycompany.com.pem -inkey key.pem -name xxx.mycompany.com -out test.pks
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass 123456 -destkeystore test.jks -srckeystore test.pks -srcstoretype PKCS12
keytool -import -alias bundle -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle.crt -keystore test.jks
```

After Nexus restart I can't not reach it by URL `//xxx.mycompany.com:8443`. Firefox says:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the
>   authenticity of the received data could not be verified

Also trying to do: `docker login xxx.mycompany.com:8443` and providing default `admin:admin:123` credentials cause:

> Error response from daemon: Get xxx.mycompany.com:8443/v1/users/:
>   x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I also try to chain certificates by various scenarions from Google, including [How to add certificate chain to keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062072/how-to-add-certificate-chain-to-keystore), but got error on Docker:

> Error response from daemon: Get //xxx.mycompany.com:8443/v1/users/: EOF

on Firefox, the same as first time and on Chrome:

> //xxx.mycompany.com unexpectedly closed the connection

**Question:** Where is my mistake, or how to correctly install CA certificate on Nexus3?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the resolution. Just needed to set in `jetty-https.xml` next lines:

```
<Set name="NeedClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.needClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
<Set name="WantClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.wantClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
```